# how to add scroll button on list view?

Tags: android, listview

i have seen one think in android list view there is one small button on right side to scrolling list. like astro provide a right side button to scrolling a list and it visible while scrolling the list and invisible when it ideal.

I dont have idea to how to done this. but i m thinking there is only one property to enable this.

Please provide ans if anybody use that.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 4):

i find the ans we can enable bye following propery og listview in xml

> android:fastScrollEnabled="true"

Answer (score 0):

You can set one property in listview that is fastScrollEnabled="true" ..

But right side button is visible only when you have more than 10(appx) number of data in the listview it can not see when you have 5-6 records..

```
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
```